# Why a new file with ~ added in extension is created whenever I create a file

Tags: files

I created a file in Ubuntu command prompt like this

```
$ gedit first_file.txt
```

After editing and saving the file when do `ls` on command prompt I can see an additional file created

```
first_file.txt~
```

**My Question**

1. What is this file and why it is created?
2. Will it ok to tell Ubuntu not to created these files and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are backup copies.

To control the creation of those:
`Edit -> Preferences -> Editor` and look for "File Saving".

[image]